# iOS Swift: Adding bottom insets between section in Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to add some space between the last cell of a section and the header of the next section if the table is a plain type

How can I do that?

Comment: Simply just Add Footer to the section.

Comment: Make the table view Style from Plain to Grouped or if you want to continue as it plain, please add a Footer to the first section

Comment: I need a Plain style. And If I add the footer, I have it sticked while I don't need it

Comment: Is there any reason for plain tableview style ?

Comment: yup, I need the sticky header

Comment: To avoid sticky footer, use 
allowsFooterViewsToFloat() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 20
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    return UIView()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Footer View

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    return UIView()
}
```

To avoid sticky footer, use allowsFooterViewsToFloat() function

```
public extension UITableView {

    func allowsHeaderViewsToFloat() -> Bool {

        return true
    }

    func allowsFooterViewsToFloat() -> Bool {

        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just add empty cell at the end of section.